# Fastest way to check for value existence

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of values I have to check my input against it for existence.

What is the fastest way?

This is really out of curiosity on how the internals work, not any stuff about premature optimization etc...

1.

```
$x=array('v'=>'','c'=>'','w'=>);

..

..

array_key_exists($input,$x);
```

2.

```
$x=array('v','c','w');

..

..

in_array($input,$x);
```

Comment: Why not to take a peek into PHP source code, if you really curious on how the internals work?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel eventually I'll do it, but I am just in the beginning of learning the internals of PHP, and I do it in a structured way. The current question came from an argument I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `isset($x[$input])` which, if suitable for your needs, would generally beat both of those presented.

Of the two methods in the question, `array_key_exists` has less work to do than `in_array` so if you had to choose between only those two then `array_key_exists` would be it.

Aside: Do you have any specific questions about "the internals"?

Comment: @Itay Moav, try it and see. In most cases it would be. And it's *shorter* thus saving our poor, tired fingers.

Comment: Yeah @Itay try it and see. But try using apache bemchmark with real code, not "zillion iterations of nothing"

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, array_key_exists is faster 99% of the time, especially as the array size grows.

that being said, isset is even faster, as it does a hash lookup vs an array value search, though isset will return false on blank values, as shown in your example array.

Comment: `isset` works fine with "blank" values, though `NULL` would be the case to keep in mind.

Comment: empty will, not isset will not

Comment: damn, nice catch, wasn't thinking when i posted this :)